# Python: NameError: free variable 're' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python

I have a strange NameError in Python 3.3.1 (win7).

The code:

```
import re

# ...

# Parse exclude patterns.
excluded_regexps = set(re.compile(regexp) for regexp in options.exclude_pattern)

# This is line 561:
excluded_regexps |= set(re.compile(regexp, re.I) for regexp in options.exclude_pattern_ci)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py3createtorrent.py", line 794, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "py3createtorrent.py", line 561, in main
    excluded_regexps |= set(re.compile(regexp, re.I) for regexp in options.exclude_pattern_ci)
  File "py3createtorrent.py", line 561, in <genexpr>
    excluded_regexps |= set(re.compile(regexp, re.I) for regexp in options.exclude_pattern_ci)
NameError: free variable 're' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

Note that line 561, where the error occurs, is the *second* line in the code above. In other words: `re` is *not* a free variable. It is simply the regular expression module and it can be referenced perfectly fine in the *first* line.

It seems to me that the reference to `re.I` is causing the problem, but I don't see how.

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove `re.I` from line 561? I doubt it-- The problem is most likely caused by something you left out of your question.

Comment: Try to provide a http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @alexis You are right. The error does not go away if I remove `re.I`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most likely, you are assigning to `re` (presumably inadvertently) at some point *below* line 561, but in the same function. This reproduces your error:

```
import re

def main():
    term = re.compile("foo")
    re = 0

main()
```

Comment: You are right. I imported the re module somewhere below that line again (locally into the function scope). What I don't get however is why Python did not complain about the first line then...

Comment: Glad it worked. If you can construct a minimal example that reproduces your problem, we can explain the python semantics for you. Right now you really don't give enough information.

Comment: Here is a script that reproduces the error: http://pastebin.com/yQN89y4A Python throws a NameError in line 13 (as opposed to line 12).

Comment: your code did not raise on line 12 because the iterable is empty; so the genexp body did not run.

Answer (score 12):

"free variable" in the traceback suggests that this is a local variable in an enclosing scope.  something like this:

```
 baz = 5

 def foo():
     def bar():
         return baz + 1

     if False:
          baz = 4

     return bar()
```

so that the `baz` is referring to a local variable (the one who's value is 4), not the (presumably also existing) global.  To fix it, force `baz` to a global:

```
 def foo():
     def bar():
         global baz
         return baz + 1
```

so that it won't try to resolve the name to the nonlocal version of baz.  Better yet, find where you're using `re` in a way that looks like a local variable (generator expressions/list comprehensions are a good place to check) and name it something else.

Answer (score 1):

The other explanations are perfect, but let me add another variant which I just discovered. Due to Python 3 preferring iterators over 'physical' lists one has to be more careful:

```
def foo():
    re = 3
    faulty = filter(lambda x: x%re, range(30))
    del re
    return faulty
list(foo())
```

The filter expression only gets evaluated after the return statement in the last line, in particular after `del re`. Hence the last line explodes with the error:

```
NameError: free variable 're' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```