# Convert pandas dataframe of lists to dict of dataframes

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe (with a DateTime index) , in which some of the columns contain lists, each with 6 elements.

```
In: dframe.head()
Out: 
                           A                                        B  \
timestamp                                                                
2017-05-01 00:32:25        30  [-3512, 375, -1025, -358, -1296, -4019]   
2017-05-01 00:32:55        30  [-3519, 372, -1026, -361, -1302, -4020]   
2017-05-01 00:33:25        30  [-3514, 371, -1026, -360, -1297, -4018]   
2017-05-01 00:33:55        30  [-3517, 377, -1030, -363, -1293, -4027]   
2017-05-01 00:34:25        30  [-3515, 372, -1033, -361, -1299, -4025]   
                                                      C           D
timestamp                                                             
2017-05-01 00:32:25  [1104, 1643, 625, 1374, 5414, 2066]      49.93   
2017-05-01 00:32:55  [1106, 1643, 622, 1385, 5441, 2074]      49.94   
2017-05-01 00:33:25  [1105, 1643, 623, 1373, 5445, 2074]      49.91   
2017-05-01 00:33:55  [1105, 1646, 620, 1384, 5438, 2076]      49.91   
2017-05-01 00:34:25  [1104, 1645, 613, 1374, 5431, 2082]      49.94
```

I have a dictionary `dict_of_dfs` which I want to populate with 6 dataframes,

```
dict_of_dfs = {1: df1, 2:df2, 3:df3, 4:df4, 5:df5, 6:df6}
```

where the *ith* dataframe contains the *ith* items from each list, so the first dataframe in the dict will be:

```
In:df1
Out: 
                            A          B      C        D
    timestamp                                                                
    2017-05-01 00:32:25        30  -3512   1104    49.93
    2017-05-01 00:32:55        30  -3519   1106    49.94
    2017-05-01 00:33:25        30  -3514   1105    49.91
    2017-05-01 00:33:55        30  -3517   1105    49.91
    2017-05-01 00:34:25        30  -3515   1104    49.94
```

and so-on.
The actual dataframe has more columns than this and thousands of rows.
What's the simplest, most python way to make the conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and for select values of `lists` use `str[0]`, `str[1]`:

```
N = 6
dfs = {i:df.assign(B=df['B'].str[i-1], C=df['C'].str[i-1]) for i in range(1,N + 1)}

print(dfs[1])
             timestamp   A     B     C      D
0  2017-05-01 00:32:25  30 -3512  1104  49.93
1  2017-05-01 00:32:55  30 -3519  1106  49.94
2  2017-05-01 00:33:25  30 -3514  1105  49.91
3  2017-05-01 00:33:55  30 -3517  1105  49.91
4  2017-05-01 00:34:25  30 -3515  1104  49.94
```

Another solution:

```
dfs = {i:df.apply(lambda x: x.str[i-1] if type(x.iat[0]) == list else x) for i in range(1,7)}

print(dfs[1])
             timestamp   A     B     C      D
0  2017-05-01 00:32:25  30 -3512  1104  49.93
1  2017-05-01 00:32:55  30 -3519  1106  49.94
2  2017-05-01 00:33:25  30 -3514  1105  49.91
3  2017-05-01 00:33:55  30 -3517  1105  49.91
4  2017-05-01 00:34:25  30 -3515  1104  49.94
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [185]: %timeit {i:df.assign(B=df['B'].str[i-1], C=df['C'].str[i-1]) for i in range(1,N+1)}
1 loop, best of 3: 420 ms per loop

In [186]: %timeit {i:df.apply(lambda x: x.str[i-1] if type(x.iat[0]) == list else x) for i in range(1,7)}
1 loop, best of 3: 447 ms per loop

In [187]: %timeit {(i+1):df.applymap(lambda x: x[i] if type(x) == list else x) for i in range(6)}
1 loop, best of 3: 881 ms per loop
```

Comment: I add another solution without specifying column names, please check it.

Comment: Looks good, same as teh solution from @Allen above. It also works for me in console but when included in my script I get `NameError: ("free variable 'type' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope", 'occurred at index duration')` Any idea why??

Comment: I think there is problem some variable is called `type` what is also code word in python. So try change variable name. Ans solution is a bit changed, because faster ;)

Comment: I agree that's what it looks like, but there is no variable called `type` in my script

Comment: Or typo? Check `()`

Comment: Hmm, I find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545262/python-nameerror-free-variable-re-referenced-before-assignment-in-enclosing) and it seems in your code have `=` not `==` in `type(x.iat[0]) == list`

Comment: No , I have `==` . Someone suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778685/nameerror-free-variable-type-referenced-before-assignment-in-enclosing-scop?noredirect=1#comment74597887_43778685) to use `type(x.iat[0]) is list` but that also gives the same error

Comment: It seems it is bug, maybe your python is broken. Is possible check your real data code in another PC? I try many ways, but I cannot simulate your problem.

Comment: I found this line in my exception handling: `type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()`

Comment: Yes, and there is error. Huraaay!!!!!! This type of error are really bad :(

Comment: And try restart pc after rename. because `python` remember it witout restarting.

Answer (score 3):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'2017-05-01 00:32:25': 30,
  '2017-05-01 00:32:55': 30,
  '2017-05-01 00:33:25': 30,
  '2017-05-01 00:33:55': 30,
  '2017-05-01 00:34:25': 30},
 'B': {'2017-05-01 00:32:25': [-3512, 375, -1025, -358, -1296, -4019],
  '2017-05-01 00:32:55': [-3519, 372, -1026, -361, -1302, -4020],
  '2017-05-01 00:33:25': [-3514, 371, -1026, -360, -1297, -4018],
  '2017-05-01 00:33:55': [-3517, 377, -1030, -363, -1293, -4027],
  '2017-05-01 00:34:25': [-3515, 372, -1033, -361, -1299, -4025]},
 'C': {'2017-05-01 00:32:25': [1104, 1643, 625, 1374, 5414, 2066],
  '2017-05-01 00:32:55': [1106, 1643, 622, 1385, 5441, 2074],
  '2017-05-01 00:33:25': [1105, 1643, 623, 1373, 5445, 2074],
  '2017-05-01 00:33:55': [1105, 1646, 620, 1384, 5438, 2076],
  '2017-05-01 00:34:25': [1104, 1645, 613, 1374, 5431, 2082]},
 'D': {'2017-05-01 00:32:25': 49.93,
  '2017-05-01 00:32:55': 49.94,
  '2017-05-01 00:33:25': 49.1,
  '2017-05-01 00:33:55': 49.91,
  '2017-05-01 00:34:25': 49.94}})
```

#### Solution

Construct the df dict using dict comprehension. The sub df is generated using the applymap function. It can convert all columns with a list of 6 elements:

```
dict_of_dfs = {(i+1):df.applymap(lambda x: x[i] if type(x) == list else x) for i in range(6)}

print(dict_of_dfs[1])
                      A     B     C      D
2017-05-01 00:32:25  30 -3512  1104  49.93
2017-05-01 00:32:55  30 -3519  1106  49.94
2017-05-01 00:33:25  30 -3514  1105  49.10
2017-05-01 00:33:55  30 -3517  1105  49.91
2017-05-01 00:34:25  30 -3515  1104  49.94


print(dict_of_dfs[2])
                      A    B     C      D
2017-05-01 00:32:25  30  375  1643  49.93
2017-05-01 00:32:55  30  372  1643  49.94
2017-05-01 00:33:25  30  371  1643  49.10
2017-05-01 00:33:55  30  377  1646  49.91
2017-05-01 00:34:25  30  372  1645  49.94
```

Comment: this is great that it works for all the columns that are lists without having to specify them.

Comment: This works ok for me in console, but when I include it in my script i get this message `NameError: ("free variable 'type' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope", 'occurred at index duration')` Any idea why?