# NameError: ("free variable 'type' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope"

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this code

```
dof = {i: dframe.apply(lambda x: x.str[i - 1] if type(x.iat[0]) == list else x) for i in range(1, 7)}
```

to convert a dataframe of lists to a dict of dataframes, as given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776297/convert-pandas-dataframe-of-lists-to-dict-of-dataframes/43776567?noredirect=1#comment74597447_43776567). The line works when I use it in a console, but when I include it in my script I get this message:

`NameError: ("free variable 'type' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope", 'occurred at index duration')`

Without posting my whole script, can you suggest what I should be looking for that has generated this error? There is no use of `type` as a variable in the script, nor is `x` or `i` used elsewhere as a variable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PYTHONprojects/DataDump/log_latest_from_api.py", line 138, in main
    dof = {i: dframe.apply(lambda x: x.str[i - 1] if type(x.iat[0]) is list else x) for i in range(1, 7)}
  File "C:/PYTHONprojects/DataDump/log_latest_from_api.py", line 138, in <dictcomp>
    dof = {i: dframe.apply(lambda x: x.str[i - 1] if type(x.iat[0]) is list else x) for i in range(1, 7)}
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4061, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4157, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "C:/PYTHONprojects/DataDump/log_latest_from_api.py", line 138, in <lambda>
    dof = {i: dframe.apply(lambda x: x.str[i - 1] if type(x.iat[0]) is list else x) for i in range(1, 7)}
NameError: ("free variable 'type' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope", 'occurred at index duration'
```

Comment: In your console, do a print(pd.__version__), also, include print(pd.__version__) in your log_latest_from_api.py scripts before your 'dof =...'. What are the outputs?

Comment: is there any chance you've accidentally re-assigned type? You could get around this by using Series.dtype instead of type() to test the type the objects in x.

Comment: @Allen Both show version `0.18.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal way to create such an error:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        print(type)

    bar()
    type = 1

foo()
```

In particular the problem the presence of `type = 1`, but only after the call to `bar()` which tries to use it. So while you say "There is no use of `type` as a variable in the script" I'm having trouble believing that. What other mentions of `type` in the script? Have you assigned it a value, defined it as the name of a function or class, or imported a value with that name anywhere?

Comment: I found it. My exception handling has this line: `type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()` 
- I think that was causing the error. Thanks