# NameError: free variable 'product' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, odoo

```
def action_cancel(self):
    """
    @param self: object pointer
    """
    for rec in self:
        if not rec.order_id:
            raise UserError(_("Order id is not available"))
        for product in rec.room_line_ids.filtered(
            lambda l: l.order_line_id.product_id == product
        ):
            rooms = self.env["hotel.room"].search([("product_id", "=", product.id)])
            rooms.write({"isroom": True, "status": "available"})
        rec.invoice_ids.button_cancel()
        return rec.order_id.action_cancel()
```

Could you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: [duplicate] Please view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545262/python-nameerror-free-variable-re-referenced-before-assignment-in-enclosing

Comment: What value is `product` supposed to have in `lambda l: l.order_line_id.product_id == product`?

Comment: I've already reviewed it but I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering the `room_line_ids` in your for loop as below:

```
lambda l: l.order_line_id.product_id == product
```

But the `product` variable  in the right side of the expression is not assigned to any value.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do ?

```
for product in rec.room_line_ids.mapped('order_line_id').mapped('product_id') :
```